# Kernel freeze on wake up 16.04

Tags: kernel, suspend, 16.04

I've been using ubuntu for a couple of months now and after kernel 3.56, I started seeing a problem when I wake up my pc. Basically, the first few second everything is working fine and then mouse, keyboard and everything else freezes and all I can do is power button reset pc.

> lspci | grep VGA

```
martin@HP:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0c)
```

> martin@HP:~$ sudo lshw -C video

```
martin@HP:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:91 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2050(size=8)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is Ubuntu 16.04? Ubuntu 16.04 has Linux kernel 4.4. Could you confirm it?

Comment: yeah. This problem occurs on 3.19.56; 3.19.58, 4.2 and 4.4. The problem is that I am stuck only with the old versions ....